# WPF datagrid nullreference exception when cell edit is committed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My datagrid crashes sporadically, the call stack didnt contain my code at all, so i m puzzled whats going on. The call stack ends like this:

System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup.UpdateValues()
System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup.UpdateAndValidate(ValidationStep validationStep)
System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup.CommitEdit()
System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)

Any idea what might cause this issue? I suspect it is related to some custom selection logic i implemented. However i am struggling even to reproduce the issue.

Comment: are you going to share any code ?

Comment: at this point i cant event narrow the problem, because it s so hard to reproduce

Comment: have your debug exception handler activated .. might help you..

goto -- Debug->Exceptions and tick all checkboxes

Comment: yes, it s a nullref exception from the framework, i have no idea how to proceed

Comment: well you need to recall your last few changes to know what files are complaining